# Why Beautiful Soup cannot display all <td> data in the tables?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to page scrape wikipedia a week ago. But i could not figure out why Beautiful Soup will only show some string from the table column and show "none" for other table column.

NOTE: the table column all contains data.

My program will extract all table columns with the tag "description". I am trying to extract all the description from the table.

The website I am scraping is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernatural_(season_6)

This is my code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib
import sys
from urllib import FancyURLopener

class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.65 Safari/534.24'


def printList(rowList):
    for row in rowList:
        print row
        print '\n'

    return

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernatural_(season_6)"

#f = urllib.urlopen(url)
#content = f.read()
#f.close

myopener = MyOpener()
page = myopener.open(url)
content = page.read()
page.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(content))
soup.prettify()

movieList = []

rowListTitle = soup.findAll('tr', 'vevent')
print len(rowListTitle)

#printList(rowListTitle)
for row in rowListTitle:
    col = row.next # explain this?
    if col != 'None':
        col = col.findNext("b")
        movieTitle = col.string
        movieTuple = (movieTitle,'')
        movieList.append(movieTuple)

#printList(movieList)

for row in movieList:
    print row[0]

rowListDescription = soup.findAll('td' , 'description')
print len(rowListDescription)


index = 1;
while ( index < len(rowListDescription) ):
    description = rowListDescription[index]
    print description
    print description.string
    str = description
    print '####################################'
    movieList[index - 1] = (movieList[index - 1][0],description)
    index = index + 1
```

I did not paste the output as it is really long. But the output is really weird as it did managed to capture the information in the `<td>` but when i do a `.string`, it gives me an empty content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do all the description strings come up empty? From the documentation:

> For your convenience, if a tag has only one child node, and that child node is a string, the child node is made available as tag.string, as well as tag.contents[0].

In this case, the description often have child nodes, i.e.: a `<a>` link to another Wikipedia article. This counts as a *non-string* child node, in which case `string` for the description node is set to `None`.

Comment: Thanks Camille. tag.contents[0] did help to retrieve the first NavigableString.